# "No ReverseMatch" while supplying kwargs with arguments that match view in urls.py

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I have read through some of the answers already on stackoverflow regarding this, but I cannot see any errors I'm making in the code below. From my point of view there should not be any reason for it not to work, also I checked the documentation that says that this syntax should be the one to use. I am however still getting a "No ReverseMatch" so something is wrong.

I have the following urls.py entry:

```
url(r'^portfolio/profile/(?P<profile_id>[0-9]+)$', views.portfolio_view_profile, name='view_investment_profile')
```

Then I have the following class based view:

```
class PortfolioDividendEdit(PortfolioEditBase):
    model = Dividend
    form_class = DividendForm
    template_name = 'plan/portfolio/edit/dividend_edit.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if "delete" in self.request.POST:
            div_obj = Dividend.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['dividend_id'])
            profile_id = div_obj.profile_id
            # obj.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('plan:view_investment_profile'), kwargs={'profile_id': profile_id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PortfolioEditBase, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        dividend_obj = Dividend.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['dividend_id'])
        profile = Profile.objects.get(id=dividend_obj.profile_id)
        context['post_req'] = self.post_req
        context['profile'] = profile
        context['dividend_id'] = self.kwargs['dividend_id']
        return context

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = Dividend.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['dividend_id'])
        return obj

    def get_success_url(self):
        dividend_obj = Dividend.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['dividend_id'])
        profile_id = dividend_obj.profile_id
        return reverse(self.url_name, args=[profile_id])
```

I was originally going to reverse it to a DeleteView, but then its only like four lines of code to delete the object so why then bother with creating an additional view for that. That being said I had created the DeleteView class but got the same error there as well (No ReverseMatch) and a bunch of other different reverse errors that I did not understand.

Anyway, the following line is the problem:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('plan:view_investment_profile'), kwargs={'profile_id': profile_id})
```

This line gives the following error:

```
Reverse for 'view_investment_profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'plan/portfolio/profile/(?P<profile_id>[0-9]+)$']
```

Please note that I have commented out the delete() call as I dont want to be deleting objects at this time.

As you can see I have supplied the appropriate view with the necessary keyword arguments to be taken to that view, still it gives me a "No ReverseMatch" error.

Any ideas on this ?

Comment: Probably the `profile_id` is `None`.

Comment: No it isnt, I did a print of it and it showed the correct ID number

Comment: try `return reverse(self.url_name, kwargs={"profile_id": profile_id})`

Comment: Well I tried to remove the code a few times and then rewrite it a couple of times and now it suddenly works. Its nice that it works now but its the exact same code.. This is not the first time this has happened...suddenly when you rewrite the code it "magically" just works.. really annoying. I did try to use ctrl-z to get back to the code that did not work but now that worked too, so i dont know :/ @Umair I didnt try your code as it now works, as it should have the first time, but dont get why it wouldnt work previously